# What are the risks of setting a cookie to have a more global scope?

Tags: web-application, cookies

If I have a subdomain, and I set my cookie's scope to be `/` instead of `examp.example.com`. How can it be insecure?

Comment: You may find http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33851/protecting-against-cross-subdomain-cookie-attacks and answers useful

Comment: Thanks @НЛО. Actually, the scenario in the question there answers this question.

Comment: Is a defense against it to set a cookie for its own domain to avoid corss subdomain cookie attacks?

Comment: The other question is very similar, but it doesn't discuss path scoping in addition to cross-subdomain issues.

Comment: Very true. hmm..I need to read more on the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about two different scoping properties.  `examp.example.com` is a domain scope, and `/` is a path scope.

`/` means that the cookie is valid for any URL path within the relevant domain scope.  `examp.example.com` is that relevant domain scope.

To answer the question in your comment, yes, you want to specifically scope your cookies to your sub-domain to prevent them from being sent along with requests to other sub-domains, where they could be read by those who have no business reading them.   So you do **not** want to scope cookies that are specifically for `examp.example.com` to `.example.com`, or rely on any cookies that are scoped to `example.com`.

Comment: So by controlling the scope I can mitigate cross subdomain cookie attacks right?

Comment: Yes. I believe the principle of an attack taking advantage of this is in finding an XSS vulnerability but not being able to intercept the cookies, so instead you use your XSS to have the cookie sent to another domain that you can intercept from (if the scope allows this). Therefore you should implement the strictest scope that allows the app to function.

Comment: So the path should be examp.example/ . The path determines the scope, isnt it.. Isnt there also a danger in grabbing the cookie of the subdomain in the sites main domain with XSS?

Comment: No.   The domain should be examp.example.com, and the path should be /, or something more restrictive, like /admin (If you only want the cookie to be sent to URLs containing examp.example.com/admin as the root path, for example.)

Comment: Another question. Why cant I see the domain attribute when I intercept requests say with fiddler